# Formatting Flutter codebase on GitLab CI in a merge request

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I can add the following `script:flutter format` to my CI yml file, and in the pipeline output I can see it finds files to format and does the formatting:

```
$ flutter format ./lib ./test
Formatting directory ./lib:
Formatted main.dart
Formatting directory ./test:
Unchanged widget_test.dart
```

But when it's finished I check the Pull Request, and the files are unchanged. How do I take the files that were formatting via my pipeline, and replace them in the pull request itself?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use it as a CI check in order for the pull request to become approved?

Push the flutter format command down to your developers as a standard for checking in good code (personal opinion). This way the CI check fails and the PR assignee takes care of it with another commit (and next time doesn't commit unformatted code).

Note: To check in the formatted files that are updated in the pipeline, you have to try something I'm not as well versed on (and maybe should be?): committing the updated files back to the repo (your script only runs the format command locally, and you haven't given it a command on where to save the changes, so it just leaves it alone). Maybe something like this? https://github.com/marketplace/actions/add-commit